# If $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with a) the discrete topology and b)indiscrete topology, are they normal, regular, or both?

Tags: general-topology

So if $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $\mathcal{D}$ the discrete topology is is normal, regular or both?

I have its neither normal or regular since the discrete topology is all subsets of X that are open and closed.

So if $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $\mathcal{I}$ the discrete topology is is normal, regular or both?

I'm thinking its both normal and regular but I'm not sure on that

Answer (score 1):

Normal means you can separate closed disjoint sets. So for the discrete, if you have two disjoint sets (closed since everything is closed)  take the sets themselves to be your open neighbourhood separating the closed sets. Normal always implies regular in T_1 spaces (Why?)

What can you say for the trivial topology? What are the closed sets?